# Php Get request with client parameters

Tags: php, get-request

I need to make a http get request in php. So far I have the php go to the url and login via the username and password parameters.

However the url I am trying to access generates a token using my ip. However this generates the token using the ip of my webserver that is making the request. How can I make it use the ip of whatever device is accessing the file and almost forward it on?

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you post the code you are currently using? Do you use curl or some other method?

Comment: At the moment I’m using a stream and encoding the username and password parameters in base64 then optimum the file

Comment: I think if you include the code in your question it might be easier for people to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$userIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: Would this transfer to the url that I am sending the get request to?

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` contains the IP address of the remote host requesting the page.

Comment: Not always, depends on the setup

Comment: True, a proxy or VPN may alter this; there is the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, but that can be spoofed relatively easily. REMOTE_ADDR is the only "guaranteed" REAL address.

Comment: How would I use this To make the url I am accessing use the ip of the device instead of my web server?